# Regex for multidimensional input string name to get the the last number between quare brackets

Tags: regex, mach

Is there someone to help me with my regex?

I want to match always last integer suquare bracket for every string.

```
product[attribute][1][0][value] - In this case [0]
product[attribute][9871][56][value] - In this case [56]
```

[Click here for My work](https://regex101.com/r/w1oS0p/1):

```
/\[[0-9,-]+\]/g
```

The goal is to increment input name on clone, `product[attribute][{attribute_id}][{clone_index}][value]`.

Comment: So if your input is `product[attribute][1][0][value]`, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```js
var s = "product[attribute][1][0][value]";
console.log(s.replace(
            /(.*\[)(\d+)(?=])/, function($0, $1, $2) { 
               return $1 + (Number($2)+1);
            })
)
```

The regex matches

- `(.*\[)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `[`
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(?=])` - a `]` char must appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Incrementing is done inside the callback method.

Comment: Close enough... I'm using jquery replace for this and i need a Full match only number or whole brackets.

Comment: @DobraAdrian I thought you needed the numbers as the end output. Please add the details to the question. What is the goal?

Comment: The goal is to increment input name on clone.

product[attribute][{attribute_id}][{clone_index}][value]

Comment: Yep, that's it, Thanx. You are a superhero :D